# (MTM) Microsoft Test Manager. Is it possible to run one test on all machines at time?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I use MS Test Manager to run coded UI tests on test machines, and need to run single test on completely all machines at time.

But http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff950318.aspx says that tests are distributed into machines sequentially.

If it's impossible to do so, I guess, this limitation is a great disadvantage of MTM.

So is there a way to run one test on all machines through MTM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do that that I am aware of.
The distribution MTM is doing is for load balancing, so if you have 100 tests and 2 servers, 50 will run in server A and 50 in server B.

You could however create different plans and assign tests to different roles.